# How to free member variable malloc memory in a destructor

Tags: c++

```
//Constructor

    page_frames = (Page*) malloc(page_count*PAGE_SIZE);
    for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < page_count; ++i) {
        page_frames = new Page[PAGE_SIZE];
        page_frames++;
}

//Destructor

    free(page_frames)
```

page_frames is a member variable of type Page*.
Whether I try to deallocate the memory in the destructor, valgrind returns "Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()".

I would like to free up the memory left by malloc() to prevent any leaks.
Is there a way to free memory of a member variable in the class destructor?

Comment: `page_frames = (Page*) malloc(page_count*PAGE_SIZE);` then `page_frames = new Page[PAGE_SIZE];` repeatedly loses the old address and leaks memory. It isn't working because you no longer have the right address(es). free with value returned by malloc. delete[] with values returned by new[]

Comment: Or better use collection classes and/or smart pointers.

Comment: ... and then `page_frames` gets incremented anyway, yet another reason why the original pointer is lost, and attempting to `free` it will end in tears. Can you explain, in your own words, what the shown C++ code, that allocates the memory, you expect to do, and how, exactly, you expect it to work? And why, exactly, do you `malloc` something, and `new` other things? Why do you believe you need to use both? This has all the telltale signs of copy/paste-based programming, where random chunks of code, from various searches, get glued together in hopes that the end result works.

Comment: Yeah, I'd just use `std::vector` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `page_frames` is a member variable declared as `Page* page_frames` in your class declaration. And you are attempting to create an "array of Pages"

This:

```
page_frames = (Page*) malloc(page_count*PAGE_SIZE);
for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < page_count; ++i) {
    page_frames = new Page[PAGE_SIZE];
    page_frames++;
}
```

Has several issues. The initial malloc'd `page_frames` gets overwritten on the first iteration of the loop by the `new` call. The other issue is that pages_frames itself is getting adjusted to something else each time you invoke `page_frames++`. Hence, your `free(page_frames)` statement doesn't pass the value that was returned from malloc.

**Option 1**

This closer to what you want:

```
page_frames = (Page*) malloc(page_count*PAGE_SIZE);
for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < page_count; ++i) {
    page_frames[i] = {}; // default construct a page
}
```

But that's using C allocation semantics instead of C++ style allocations for objets. We can do better.

**Option 2**

Keep to using C++ allocation semantics.

This is even simpler and doesn't require a for-loop

```
page_frames = new Page[page_count];
```

And your corresponding destructor statement is this;

```
delete [] page_frames;
```

**Option 3**

No explicit allocation/deletion require. Let the C++ collection class library do the hard work for you.

Declare `page_frames` as `std::vector<Page>`.

And your constructor is just this:

```
page_frames.resize(page_count);
```

And no destructor work needed.